# read xml file and export to csv in java. Sample XML is below

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, export-to-csv

```
**XML**
```

This is the sample XML file which I need to export to CSV using JAVA. And Sample CSV which I want is below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
${_INCL:src:file:conf/tenant_config/merckcert/default/__rsrc/email/sig-data/sig_includes.txt}
<!DOCTYPE EmailTemplate SYSTEM "email-template.dtd">
<EmailTemplate>
<!--default/ack_org_orgn_sub_fis.xml -->
<!-- mail sent to Org-admins, AO and FISA when Org requests to subscribe to FIS -->
<SmtpHeaders>
${_INCL:incl:hdr_addrs}
  <Address Type="To" AddrList="${_ORG:tisa.emails}" />
  ${_IF:'${_ORG:appa.email}' != null 
  {<Address Type="To" AddrList="${_ORG:appa.email}" />
  }}{}
  ${_IF:'${_ORG:ao.email}' != null 
  {<Address Type="To" AddrList="${_ORG:ao.email}" />
  }}{}
  
  <Header Name="Subject" Value="${_INCL:incl:app_ref_name} Application Subscription Request Received" />
</SmtpHeaders>
<Body>

Dear Administrators, 

Your ${_INCL:incl:org_text_lower} has requested subscription to the following application:

- ${_ORG:appa.sp}

This request is currently under review, and you will be notified when your request is approved or denied.

Confirmation Code : ${_ORG:wfinst.ref}

${_INCL:incl:full_footer}
</Body>
</EmailTemplate>
```

Sample CSV file which I need is-

| Header | Body |
| --- | --- |
| Name & Value | Dear Administrators,...till the last sentence in Body |

Note: While reading the XML file in second line I was facing issue.

Comment: Where is your input XML sample?

Comment: Thanks for replying. In the description only I have given XML file.